# Facebook-like-box Safari issue: appears in some browsers, disappears in others

Tags: facebook, facebook-likebox

I have put a facebook like box on a website i've created, and on my computer it all works fine (safari, chrome, firefox, ie, ...)

But when some of my friends open the website in safari, de box won't show to everybody. 
(so some friends can see it in safari, with others it just won't show/appears and disappears immediatly/...)

Here's the iframe-code i've included

```
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FLuca-Barassii%2F126244157780&width=300&height=340&colorscheme=dark&show_faces=true&border_color&stream=false&header=false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:340px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>
```

hope anyone can help me... :)

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to their version of Safari. This browser's webkit had problems interpreting ampersands in urls in a previous version, encoding the `&` to `&#38;` instead of `&amp;` in xhtml pages. This was fixed in a later Webkit.

But to make sure, you can encode your iframe url yourself:

```html
<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?
    href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fpages%2FLuca-Barassii%2F126244157780
    &amp;width=300&amp;height=340&amp;colorscheme=dark&amp;show_faces=true
    &amp;border_color=&amp;stream=false&amp;header=false" 
    scrolling="no" 
    frameborder="0" 
    style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:340px;" 
    allowTransparency="true">
</iframe>
```

This would not have stopped the box from not showing in specific (older) versions of Safari though, because the ampersands would still have been encoded incorrectly.